# How to specify output path of binary file for Go in VS Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

My launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "remotePath": "",
        "port": 2345,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app",
        "env": {
            "GO_ENV":"dev"
            },
        "args": [],
        "showLog": true
    }
]
```

}

I want that when I'm running debug binary file with name "debug", it appears in the "app" folder. How can I specify a different output path?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `outDir` setting for specifying.